# Does it make a difference which cat I wreak havoc with?

Tags: crashy-cats

I can unlock various cats, usually through the gift boxes. Are the different cats just cosmetically different? Or do they have differences in terms of abilities or the like?

Answer (score 1):

I have been running random cats with random headgear and have noticed no difference between the behaviour, response, and havoc-wreaking skills of any of the animal/headgear combinations.

I have tested this up to and including the Panda bear.